# CSS/JS permissions

Tags: javascript, webforms, 9

When I add CSS/JavaScript to webforms using the menu under settings-> css/js , it works for users with the  administrator role, but it fails to work for all other user roles.The page loads but the CSS/JS doesn't.

Is there a setting to give permissions to other roles?

Error logs when checking browser console are:

```
GET
http://172.31.162.16/drupal9/webform/javascript/nbr_contact_summary?s97t31
net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (500 Service unavailable (with message))

nbr-contact-summary:1 Refused to apply style from
'http://172.31.162.16/drupal9/webform/css/nbr_contact_summary?s97t31' because
its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and
strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from
'http://172.31.162.16/drupal9/webform/javascript/nbr_contact_summary?s97t31'
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type
checking is enabled.
```

Comment: The requests are failing, that's pretty much all anyone could say from here. Check your Drupal and server logs, they will most likely contain more information

Comment: Custom css/js added from settings page are not role restricted by design. Try with a simple alert or console log to validate this